# ColdFusion - Invalid CFML Construct in cfparam

Tags: coldfusion

I am using a custom tag and am getting an Invalid CFML Construct error on the following:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 27 at column 10.

```
26 : <cfscript>
27 : cfparam( 'attributes.action', 'new' );
28 : cfparam( 'attributes.fieldList', '' );
29 : cfparam( 'attributes.return', 'variables' );
```

Comment: Sometimes CF gives the wrong line number.  Please add lines 15-25 to your question.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 5):

You are using incorrect syntax for `param`. I think you have got the `cfparam` mistaken for a simple ColdFusion function. For `cfparam` you need to specify the parameters with names like `name`, `default` when passing the data. Not as just the values for comma separated values like you can do for a normal function (like `listfind(list, 'str')`).

```
<cfscript>
  cfparam(name="attributes.action", default='new');
  param name="attributes.action" default='new';
</cfscript>
```

And the short hand syntax is `param attributes.action ='new';`

Comment: More more simply `param attributes.action ='new';`